# Непонятное поведение элементов при активном состоянии селектов

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, вёрстка

Есть форма с селектами, открытие которых приводит к смещению шапки сайта. Что интересно, происходит это только в мобильном режиме инструмента разработчика (F12 в хроме). Увидеть проблему можно здесь: [ссылка](http://cyprus.890m.com/Cyprus/agent_page.html)

[Ссылка](http://prntscr.com/cx28vo) на скрин проблемных блоков при неактивном состоянии селектов
[Ссылка](http://prntscr.com/cx29mr) на скрин проблемных блоков когда открыт один из селектов

Есть идеи, в чем причина и как устранить баг?

Answer (score 1):

Смещение происходит из-за блока `div.select2-container`, который появляется при открытии селекта, и имеет следующее правило:

```
.select2-container {
     width: 100% !important; 
}
```

Поскольку он находится в корне боди и имеет абсолютное позиционирование с отсупом от левого края, его правый край выпирает из боди и расширяет его.

Вы пытались ограничить ширину до 100%, но поскольку `.header` у Вас имеет `position: fixed`, у Вас это не вышло.

Попробуйте убрать это непонятное правило на `.select2-container`, у меня сложилось впечатление, что оно лишнее.

Comment: благодарю за Ваш ответ. Действительно, причиной смещения является указанный Вами стиль. К сожалению, лишним его не могу назвать, так как селект2 просчитывает ширину селектов лишь при загрузке страницы, при изменении её размеров селекты остаются с прежней шириной. Даже не знаю как теперь быть..